# Visual C++ stack overflow where it does not make sense

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, stack-overflow

I'm writing a 32-bit C++ application on Windows 7 using MS Visual Studio 2010. In this application I have the problem that I get a stack overflow exception at points where it does not make sense. The stack of that thread really should not contain much, and I'm generally not using recursion. If I increase the stack reserve size in the MSVS project settings, this error goes away, but then I start getting out-of-memory errors from OpenCV soon (-> out of *heap*) even though my program is well below 2 GB memory consumption, according to Windows's task manager.

But first, some background: the application is huge (ten thousands of lines of code) and posting even parts of the code won't make much sense and I'm not allowed to anyway :D. The application uses concurrency, that is, I'm creating about 10 threads myself which do  heavy work, but the libs I'm using create even more. I/O of my application is crazy, I'm receiving (and processing) sensor values at 1000 Hz, doing panorama image stitching (GPU), optical image flow analysis, h264 video stream encoding, etc., all in real-time. I have several C++ libraries in use (OpenCV for video reading / image processing, Qt 4.8 for GUI, boost for creating my own processing threads and shared memory, ...).

Some background info (you may want to skip it, the **bullet point questions below** are those I really need help with):
I'm getting stack overflow exceptions in the MSVS debugger when handing over a `cv::Mat` matrix to another function of another class. E.g. class `A`, method `A1` (executed by a `runA1()` method which is running inside a boost-thread I created myself somwehere in `A`'s initialization) obtains a `cv::Mat x`, e.g. from OpenCV's video reader, and `A::A1()` passes `x` to `B::B1(cv::Mat x)`. `B` is another class, `B1()` is a method inside it. However, upon entering `B1()` I get the stack overflow. Now I'd like to mention that *at **no** point in my program I'm using recursive function calls*, so this can't be the reason. Also, I'm *not* filling the stack massively with local variables in `A::A1()`. My problem is basically: I don't know why the stack would be that full, I also don't know how to find out what actually is on the stack of the thread that runs `A1()` (other than looking at MSVS's *Locals*-debug window, but that one doesn't tell me the size of the thread's stack in bytes). The `cv::Mat` matrices should not be the source of the problem, because they act like smart pointers. The call-stack of the thread running `A1()` has 13 elements/method-calls in it, so that can't be the issue either (again, I'm *not* using recursion). For quite some time I was able to bypass the problem by having to set both `/Zm1000` in the compiler options and increasing the stack reserve size from **1MB** (default) to **10MB**. I had to do both (yup, I do know that this is bogus, but if I didn't, e.g. if I were to just set stack reserve size to 10 without the Zm option, I'd still get stack overflows). However, since I programmed some more new features, I suddenly had to increase it to **50MB** to get it working. Knowing that the various libs I use do create many more threads beyond my control, each thread getting stack reserves of 50 MB, I realize I'm living in a dangerous world, memory-wise. And so it happens that during the execution of my code, OpenCV's allocation routines soon complain that not enough memory is available (at that point, process explorer shows a memory usage of 600 MB). I am unsure what to do about it.

So here are a few questions I've been asking myself:

- What could lead to a stack overflow, other than the obvious culprits (allocating shitloads in stack variables, and recursive function calls)?
- Are there tools or at least some native C/C++ methods available that will tell me how much stack and how much heap my program uses, with separate information for each thread?
- The memory consumption shown by the Windows task manager: is it correct at all? Does it include stack consumption? [I think the answer is yes to both, but since I'm out of ideas I have to start doing sanity checks).
- Is it possible to get out of heap memory exceptions even though my 32-bit program is well below the 2 GB memory limit (according to Windows task manager) ?

Comment: Re-set the stack size to the default value and break into the debugger when the stack overflow happens. There, look for big stack allocations in each function in the call stack. Besides big locals, watch out for calls to `alloca` and VLAs.

Comment: Weird, "impossible" behavior very often points to corruption. Examine all your pointer usage carefully. Any variadic functions? Examine those closely too.

Comment: Suggestion: Your question is unnecessarily long. You could pretty much dispose of the third paragraph entirely and just boil it down to the sentence stating you use no recursion.

Comment: Yes I will. I'm particularly hoping for helpful posts on the bullet points at the end.

Comment: After recursion another possible cause of stack overflows is large objects passed by value to functions.

Comment: One thing you can do to debug the issue is to step through one of the call sequences you mention and watch the value of the stack pointer. If there are large offsets between functions, someone is using the stack for temporary storage.

Comment: Have you looked into kernel mode debuggers? WinDbg is useful when you want to take a look at what your program is doing at a kernel level. You can get the kernel debuggers from the Windows Driver kits(WDK)

Comment: I also second @MatteoItalia's suggestions. In fact you can also try to reduce the stack to say, 100 MB as it might make the problem easier to repeat. Also try to reproduce it by doing the suspect operation directly in a piece of code run from the command line, with no threads.

Comment: Thanks for the hints so far. The behavior is infact deterministic, not sporadic. @jdv-JandeVaan I suppose you meant 100 **K**B, right? And could you please explain a bit how to see the stack pointer address in VS debugger, and what you mean with "someone is using the stack for temporary storage"?

Comment: Oh yes I meant KB. And the 'someome' would be the opencv matrix smart pointer. Perhaps it is making a copy after all.

Comment: If you are running out of stack, it is because SOMETHING, SOMEWHERE is using up a lot of stack. It may not be in the code you have written, but most likely it is somehow related to what you are doing (a good way to use far more stackspace than you actually intended is to miscalculate variable length arrays, e.g. `foo(const int x) { int a[x]; ... }` where x is a LARGE value. And yes, you can run out of heap by the same means, asking for more than what is currently available (e.g. `new int[500*1024*1024]` will use up 2GB in one fell swoop - `new int[-5]` will also do something similar)

Comment: Actually, in my code I'm not using VLA's (why would I, I simply use QList or std::vector, I'm originally a Java developer and I try to stay as high-level as possible :D). I was hoping that there are some "instrumentation apps" that can show me the content of the stack and the size of the elements on it (I now know about the WinDbg so I'll try that one). Also, the heap allocation that fails in my program is small, around 6 MB, and it fails while the program in the task manager shows a usage of ~600 MB. I'm fully aware that this cannot happen, yet it does happen.